# How Do You Analyze This Sorting Algorithm's Time Complexity?

Tags: sorting, big-o

TL;DR - A non-comparison sorting algorithm whose execution time scales based on the number of bits in the datatype; how do you properly evaluate the Big O time complexity?

I have a sorting algorithm "Bitsort" whose time complexity is dependent on the number of bits in the datatype being sorted, and not on the length of the list being sorted; for lists ranging in length from 2 elements to maximum addressable size, the number of passes over the entire list needed to fully sort it is dictated by the size of the datatype used in the list.  The simple version of bitsort  ( non-optimized but working code example below ) sorts the list 1 bit at a time.  In real world terms, this would often mean that a 32-bit system has 32 bits in both the datatype and the maximum length of a list to be sorted; and Log-base2 of 2^32 is 32.  Ergo, it could be argued that simple bitsort's time complexity goes from O(NB), where B is the number of bits, to O(NLogN) as N goes to the maximum length array the system can handle.  In absolute terms, though, as N goes to infinity, B stays constant, so it could be argued that the time complexity is O(N).

How should the time complexity be evaluated for simple bitsort?

```
import sys
from random import randrange

def checkOrder(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i - 1] > arr[i]:
            return False
    return True


def randomArray(length, height):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, length):
        result.append(randrange(0, height, 1))
    return result


def swap(arr, left, right):
    temp = arr[left]
    arr[left] = arr[right]
    arr[right] = temp
    

# pat. pending, but not a troll
def bitsort(arr, begin, end, shiftBit):
    if end-begin <= 0 or shiftBit < 0:
        return
    LP, RP = begin - 1, end + 1
    mask = 0b1 << shiftBit

    while True:
        LP += 1
        if LP > end:
            bitsort(arr, begin, end, shiftBit - 1)
            return
        elif LP == RP:
            if LP <= begin: # left has 0 or 1 el
                pass
            else: 
                bitsort(arr, begin, LP - 1, shiftBit - 1)
            if RP >= end: # right has 0 or 1 elements
                pass
            else: 
                bitsort(arr, RP, end, shiftBit - 1) 
            return
        if arr[LP] & mask == 0:
            continue
        else:
            while True:
                RP -= 1
                if RP < begin:
                    bitsort(arr, begin, end, shiftBit - 1)
                    return
                elif LP == RP:
                    if LP <= begin:  
                        if RP <= end:
                            bitsort(arr, begin, end, shiftBit - 1)
                            return
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:  
                        bitsort(arr, begin, LP - 1, shiftBit - 1) 
                    if RP >= end:  
                        pass
                    else:  
                        bitsort(arr, RP, end, shiftBit - 1) 
                    return
                if (arr[RP] & mask) >> shiftBit == 1:
                    continue
                else:
                    swap(arr, LP, RP)
                    break


def main(args):
    arr = randomArray(1000000, 2147483648)
    bitsort(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, 31)
    print(f'Proper order: {checkOrder(arr)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m going to trust that your analysis is correct and that the work done, as a function of N and B, is O(NB), and then focus on your question about how to compare this against, say, O(N log N).

The typical convention when analyzing sorting algorithms like this is - at least, from a CS theory perspective - is to classify this as O(NB) rather than O(N log N) or O(N). Here’s a few reasons why:

1. Imagine that you’re sorting a list of numbers that you know don’t have many bits in them (say, maybe US phone area codes or US zip codes, which are at most ten bits long). In that case, you could tune the algorithm to only work on the first ten bits of each number, reducing the number of passes required to sort everything. A runtime of O(NB) more clearly telegraphs this, since a B decreases the runtime drops accordingly.
2. While we’re currently using machines with word sizes that are typically 32 or 64, in principle we could crank that word size way up if we wanted to. SIMD instructions, for example, allow for parallel operations on many more bits than this. Or perhaps you’re sorting variable-length integers, like what you might do with RSA keys. In that case, we couldn’t necessarily claim that the runtime is O(N log N), since we aren’t guaranteed that B = O(log N). It also wouldn’t be correct to say that the runtime is O(N) in that latter case, since we can’t pretend that B is a constant.
3. Explicitly writing out O(NB) allows us to compare this sorting algorithm against other integer sorting algorithms. For example, we have sorting algorithms whose runtimes are O(N log B) and O(N log N / log B). Leaving the B term in makes it easier to see how these other algorithms compare against yours.
4. A runtime of O(N log N) would be incorrect for large B and much smaller N. In that case, you might do way more than O(log N) rounds of the bitsort routines.

Comment: Thank you for such a cogent response.  
1) I agree that O(NB) is a more clear communication.
2) In practical application is there ever a surprise about the maximum possible size of B?  I had not considered that possibility.
3) I am concerned that you used the term "integer sorting algorithm"; my research indicated that current implementations of floats will sort properly by bit-significance the same as integers. Also, can you please specify some of these other algorithms; are they O(1) space?
4) Perhaps O(NLog[Nmax])?

Comment: You probably wouldn’t be “surprised” by B in practice because you’d know in advance what sorts of things you were sorting. The term “integer sorting algorithm” is the common theory term for these sorts of algorithms even though, as you’ve noted, you can often use them to sort floating-point numbers. Those other algorithms are nontrivial - the first uses the y-fast trie data structure and the second uses fusion trees. They don’t use O(1) space.

Comment: Thanks again, templatetypedef .  If you are interested in learning about complex Bitsort, please let me know.  Complex ( regular? ) Bitsort can sort a list of 64-bit datatypes in 9 passes; it sorts by multiple bits at a time, not just 1.

Answer (score 0):

The argument that it's better than O(n Log n) presumes that keys are duplicated in the array.   If all the keys are unique, it will take at least log n bits to represent them.   This means if at a minimum the sort time is O(n log n), worse if the keys are more sparsely spread out.  For example, if we're talking text encoded as ASCII, it's going to much worse.